# Electric potential for positively charged central object anf negatively charged central object

Tags: electric-fields, potential

How are the values of electric potential for negatively and positively charged central particle evaluated? Is potential at a distance $d$ from negatively charged central object more than that of positively charged one as the latter one is negative?

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of the potential relativ to infinity is the same, only the sign is different.

Comment: But are they equal? I meant the value not the magnitude only

Comment: In place of 'latter' do you mean 'former'?

Comment: Are you familiar with Coulomb's law?

Comment: No I meant that for positively charged central object potential at any point is negative in value so does that mean it is less than that of the potential for negatively charged central object since its potential is positive in value?

Comment: Do you know the definition of potential? The work of transporting a positiv charge to infinity is of cause different  in sign  for a negativ charge or a positiv charge in the center. So maybe you just make sure to know the definition